# How does Schwartz kernel theorem on manifold hold

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, microlocal-analysis

For the Schwartz kernel theorem on $R^n$, the topology of $S^\prime$ is the strong one(limit topology of a directed system of Sobolev spaces, [Weak convergence in the space of tempered distributions and weighted Sobolev spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498311/weak-convergence-in-the-space-of-tempered-distributions-and-weighted-sobolev-spa)).

But on a noncompact manifold, the Sobolev spaces may not be well defined. So in this case how is the Schwartz kernel theorem proved?